# 9patch creates extra transparent borders: How to remove?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, nine-patch

I have an XML file in my Android application. The first two linear layouts look like the image below.

Layout 1 - Semi Circle

Layout 2 - Rectangle 
[image]

**Note :** *There is NO gap between the semi circle and rectangle. This gap is the problem that I'm addressing now.*

Actually Layout 1(horizontal) has three sub layouts (vertical) and the middle sub layout contains an image view which is the semi cirlce.

When I dont use a 9 patch image, there is no gap and it blends perfectly with the Layout 2. But I am required to use a 9 patch image because of the possibility of  incorrect stretching of the semi circle.

But when I do use a 9patch image, there is this weird partition created between the two layouts.

it must be a 9patch problem. but how can it be solved? 
I just require a method to use a 9patch image of this semi circle without this gap because it may look odd.

**Note :** *the 9patch dots are ONLY on the right and left empty side, not anywhere at the top and bottom.*

[image]

This is the excerpt from the XMl file :

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/name"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="2" >
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1.98"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@drawable/semicircle" />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_weight="2" >
     </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.0"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can even use just **one** 9 patch, containing both the rectangle and the semicircle.

Comment: I cannot use it as a single pic. The semi circle is supposed to act like a button. @DerGolem

Comment: @EvanB please look at the edit now.

Comment: I see. Anyway, check out your 9.png files at pixel level for transparent borders bigger than 1 px on top/bottom sides. Also ensure your controls don't have any margin or padding, possibly inherited from a style.